# how do I use the Keras Tensorboard callback with gradients during reinforcement learning?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorboard, reinforcement-learning

I'd like to use the standard Tensorboard callback with the Keras [fit](https://keras.io/models/model/) function to show weight and gradient histograms. The issue is that with reinforcement learning, there is no validation data, and  validation data is needed in the call to fit for keras to generate histograms.

[here](https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard) is the Tensorboard callback documentation. It states that for `write_grads`, `histogram_freq` must be > 0. But if `histogram_freq >0`, I need to pass in validation_data.  As mentioned, I don't (cant?) have validation data, as I'm doing reinforcement learning (not supervised learning ).

[here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/a1397169ddf8595736c01fcea084c8e34e1a3884/keras/callbacks.py#L942) is the Tensorflow callback code. It uses validation_data, but I don't really understand why. I just want a histogram of the weights and gradients, which (I think?) has nothing to do with validation data.

For example, the callback would ideally be something simple like this:

```py
tensorboard = TensorBoard(histogram_freq=1, write_grads=True, log_dir="./")

results = self.model.fit(train_x,
                         train_y, 
                         shuffle=True, 
                         epochs=epochs, 
                         callbacks=[tensorboard])
```

But of course the above code produces the (expected) error: `"If printing histograms, validation_data must be provided, and cannot be a generator."`

I am hoping someone can either:

1. Explain how to show histograms for weights and gradients without `validation_data` or
2. Explain why `validation_data` is needed. I see it in the source code, but couldn't the training data have been used instead?

Comment: Weights don't depend on inputs but activations and gradients do. Unfortunately, there aren't separate flags for them. Anyway, it should work just fine using (a subset of) your training data for validation. You can use the `validation_split` flag for this.

Comment: @Androbin Thanks! And I can go that route. Though I'm still confused: we know that since this is the `fit` function, the gradients had to be generated and applied. So why can't we simply use those gradients for the histograms without creating validation data?

Comment: Setting `validation_split=1.0` is equivalent to using the gradients from the training data.

Comment: `with_grads` is deprecated, is there any other workaround to plot the gradient?